# envio de email com pausa de 2 segundos entre emails

Tags: php, loop, swiftmailer

Tenho a biblioteca do Swiftmailer a mandar os emails corretamente, mas gostaria de fazer uma pausa de 2 segundos entre envios dos vários emails do meu array. Tentei usar o `sleep(2)` no loop, mas não funciona.

Como posso fazer isto?

```
$users = unserialize($_POST['result']);

print_r($array);

// Create the replacements array
$replacements = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $replacements[$user["email"]] = array (
    "{nome}" => $user["nome"],
    "{total}" => $user["total"]
  );

}

// Create the mail transport configuration
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create an instance of the plugin and register it
$plugin = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($replacements);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->registerPlugin($plugin);

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject("Pedido de recibos ");

// $message->setBody("Olá {nome}, agradecemos desde já a sua colaboração durante o mês de $mesde . " .
//     "Deverá enviar um recibo no total de : {total}€ para cc@cc.com no prazo limite de 5 dias");


$message->setBody("Bom dia {nome},

email msg

");


$message->setFrom("xx@xx.pt", "Top");
// Send the email
foreach($users as $user) {sleep(2);
  $message->setTo($user["email"], $user["nome"]);
  $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Isso é para evitar spam?

Comment: para evitar k seja interpretado como spam...na verdade nem é uma newsletter...sao emails legitimos automatizados e enviados pelo site...

Comment: Não precisa do delay ( sleep() ) para evitar ser caracterizado como spam.

Comment: o meu servidor disse para enviar 50 emails max por cada 10 min ... era por isso tambem...meus emails são autenticados...

Comment: @rray não sei o porquê fazem isso, mas já vi essa operação em várias bibliotecas de envio de emails. Geralmente a atribuição dos métodos que fazem a isso chama-se "queue" (fila).

Comment: Por que você não usa Cron?

Comment: Vou ver como isso funciona

Comment: nao consigo fazer a pausa de 2 segundos entre envios :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você envia emails em massa?

Se sim sugiro que diminua a frequência de envio de e-mails, uma vez que o Gmail possui estes limites. Saiba mais: Limites para envios e recebimentos de e-mails

Você adicionou um grupo grande de destinatários ao campo "Cc" ou "Cco".?

Se sim,saiba mais como: Corrigir erros de e-mails devolvidos ou recusados

Sugiro que veja também problemas com os remetentes de e-mail em massa

2°-Em quanto tempo consigo restaurar meu e-mail para envio?

esse erro, será possível enviar e-mails novamente após 1 a 24 horas